# display arrow below active active ul item

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

how can I achive something similar to the above ?

I tried adding active-item::bofore and positioning it absolute, with top:-28px. But my arrow doesn't display. I tried giving it z-index 1000; no luck it doesn't show: [image]

```css
 #choose-cat {
width: 100%;   
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: #fff;
border: 2px solid#b6d5e2;
border-radius: 4px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: bottom 20px;
}


css:.cat-items {
    position: relative;
}

.cat-items .active-item::before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #397707;
    bottom: -28px;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.cat-items .active-item::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
 <div id="choose-cat">
     <ul class="cat-items list-group list-group-horizontal list-unstyled" >
      <li class="col-sm-3 active-item  active cat-col">
         <div class="cat-item">
              <div class="cat-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-car cat-icon main-color" aria-hidden="true"> 
                </i>
              </div>
              <div class="cat-text">
                 Automative Vehicles
              </div>
          </div>                    
      </li> ....
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you update your html & css to the question?

Comment: Can you add an example code here, so I can find out what's wrong?

Comment: added example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a concept on how you can achieve the desired result. Of-course not the only way.

```css
.menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
.menu ul li span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.menu ul li:hover span,
.menu ul li.active span {
  background-color: green;
}
.menu ul li:hover,
.menu ul li.active {
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/geomicons/32/672416-triangle-up-256.png");
  background-size: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 110%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Home</span></li>
    <li><span>About Us</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span>Team</span></li>
    <li><span>Contact Us</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added class `cat-item` to `li` element instead of `div`, then

```
.cat-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
}

.cat-items .active-item::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: calc(50%);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #397707;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```